# How to find the image of the following function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Find the image of $f:\text{R} \to \text{R} $, s.t $f $ is continues and $\forall x\in \text{R}$: $$|f(x)-x\text{e}^{\sqrt{\left| x\right| }}|\leq x^4$$
My try:
$$x\text{e}^{\sqrt{\left| x\right| }}-x^4\leq f(x)\leq x\text{e}^{\sqrt{\left| x\right| }}+ x^4$$

So, if i'll prove that:$\ \lim_{x\to \infty } x\text{e}^{\sqrt{\left| x\right| }}-x^4=\infty $, then $Im\{f(x)\}=\Re$ (because, if $x\to -\infty$ $\Rightarrow f(x)\to -\infty$ as f(x) bounded by $-\infty$ from both sides).
Unfortunately, I an not allowed to use L'Hôpital's rule, neither integration.

few days ago, i asked similar (but not identical though) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620853/how-to-prove-that-lnxx-for-x-to-infty).

Comment: Your use of LaTeX is slightly confusing. +1 for showing what you did though. Maybe you can correct it yourself. The $ | |$ symbols seem to be slightly off in the 2nd expression.

Comment: What is $\mathfrak R$ here?

Comment: What is the definition of the exponential function used in your course? But even if only $e^x\ge 1+x$ is known, you can then use $e^x=(e^{x/n})^n\ge (1+x/n)^n$ for instance with $n=8$ or $n=12$.

Comment: @Vishesh: Corrected.

Comment: @Gaffney: I meant the reals.

Comment: @LutzL: Actually we didn't define it in a formal way. I suppose that we are intended to do some algebraic games that eventually would led to a limit of the form $\text{e}*\infty$

Comment: As I wrote, $e^x=(e^{x/n})^n≥(1+x/n)^n\ge x^n/n^n$ is one of those algebraic games. Use with n=8, then $x\exp(\sqrt x)\ge x^5/8^8=x^4(x/8^8)$ and now consider $x>8^8$.

Comment: @LutzL: Thank you very much! Your suggestion solved the problem eventually.

Answer (score 1):

So,Do you ask for a good estimation of $e^{\sqrt{|x|}}$ ?. If you do, then you may try this:

$ a^x \ge ln(a)x \forall a \ge 1; x \ge 0$
**Proof**

 Denote $ g(x)=a^x(a>1)$ , we have $ g'(x) =ln(a).a^x >ln(a) \forall x>0 $
Therefore $ g(x)-g(0) \ge ln(a).x \forall x \ge 0$
, which leads to conclusion

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately we are not allowed to use derivatives.

Comment: Maybe, you would like this: $a^n -1=(a-1)(a^{n-1}+..+1) \ge n(a-1) \forall n \in \mathbb{N}; a>1 $<br>Therefore, $ a^x > [x](a-1)$, where $ [.]$ is floor function.