# Limit of $\frac{e^{x}}{\ln(x)}$

Tags: limits, exponential-function

I don't know how to find the limit
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x}{\log x}.$$
How can I do this ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is highly dependent on what you can use.

Answer (score 5):

For $x > 1$,
$$
\frac{e^x}{\ln x}
> \frac{1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!}}{x} > \frac{x}{2} \to \infty.
$$
The relevant inequalities can be proved by elementary means;
see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620853/how-to-prove-that-lnxx-for-x-to-infty) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667998/show-that-ex-1-x-x2-2-cdots-xk-k-for-n-geq-0-x-0-by-in/668010).

Comment: @DanielFischer I see.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the [L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) which, in this case, in view of the answer given by Goos, would be like killing a fly with a cannon...

I am giving you this information because L'Hôpital's rule is quite useful in some much more difficult problems involving limits (see the link for such examples), so it's good to know it.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{\exp(x)}{\ln(x)} > \frac{\exp(x)}{x} > x$

First part because $x > \ln(x)$

Second part because $\exp(x) > x^2$ as $x^2 = \exp(2 \cdot \ln(x))$ and $x > 2 \cdot \ln(x)$ for $x$ greater than 2. And exponential is an increasing function

Comment: Hi, you should use `\exp` for the exponential function, `\ln` for natural log, and `\cdot` for multiplication.

Comment: I see that you edited with the correct format, but I can't see the edited post for some reason. I'll make sure to remember this.

Answer (score 0):

$$e^x>x\log x,\quad x\ge 1,$$
since $e=e^1<1\cdot\log 1=0$ and
$$e^x=\frac{d}{dx}e^x<\frac{d}{dx}(x\log x)=1+\log x.$$